# Probability of drawing white ball from last urn

Tags: probability

I've been strugling with problem for a while. Task is from one of old probability exams.

We have $k$ urns, each has number from range $1\dots k$. On the beggining, every urn has $b$ black balls and $w$ white balls. We start from numer $1$.
In each step, we draw ball from number $s$ and put it to the urn with higher number($s+1$). In last step we draw ball from $k$-th urn. What is probability that this ball is white?

I tried basic 'tree method' to see some regularity and i came up with simple random variable 
$B_k = \text{#of white balls in k-th urn}$ 
So our probability would be 
$$P(B_k=w | B_{k-1}=w) = \frac{b+1}{b+1+w}$$
$$P(B_k=w+1 | B_{k-1} = w) = \frac{w}{b+1+w}$$
$$P(B_k=w | B_{k-1} = w+1) = \frac{b}{b+1+w}$$
$$P(B_k=w+1 | B_{k-1} = w+1) = \frac{w+1}{b+1+w}$$
for $k>2$
 but from here i can't move forward to calculate what i need and i'm not really sure my thoughts are correct. I'd appreciate some help or hint on this task. Cheers!

Comment: What does "put it to the urn with higher number" mean? Do we randomly choose any urn with a higher number?

Comment: I think it means the next number.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that. First we draw from 1st urn, put it to 2nd urn, draw from 2nd urn, put it to 3rd urn and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you had $n=2$ urns. Then $$\begin{align*}P(B_2=w)&=P(B_2=w \mid B_1=w)P(B_1=w)+P(B_2=w \mid B_1=b)P(B_1=b)=\\[0.2cm]&=\frac{(w+1)}{b+w+1}\frac{w}{b+w}+\frac{w}{b+w+1}\frac{b}{b+w}=\frac{w^2+w+bw}{(b+w+1)(b+w)}=\\[0.2cm]&=\frac{w(b+w+1)}{(b+w+1)(b+w)}=\frac{w}{b+w}\end{align*}$$ This tells us that we practically start over after every step (it is also possible to prove it inductively if necessary) and therefore $$P(B_n=w)=\frac{w}{b+w}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $k=1$ then we find probability $\frac{w}{w+b}$.

If $k=2$ then we find probability $\frac{w}{w+b}\times\frac{w+1}{w+b+1}+\frac{b}{w+b}\times\frac{w}{w+b+1}=\frac{w}{w+b}$.

This opens the door to prove by induction that we find probability $\frac{w}{w+b}$ for every $k$.